Expected value of sum of squared residuals for simple linear regression coming out to be n times variance of the error term
Here's some context:

in simple linear regression we assume $y = \beta_0 + x\beta_1 + \epsilon$ regardless of the true functional form underlying the dataset causing $\epsilon$ to have both epistemic and aleatoric components
$\hat{\beta}_0$ and $\hat{\beta}_1$ are our estimates of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ using the samples collected, respectively
n is the number of samples
$\bar{x}$ is the sample mean of $x_i$, $\bar{y}$ is the sample mean of $y_i$, and $\bar{\epsilon}$ is the sample mean of $\epsilon_i$
we assume that $cov[\epsilon_i, \epsilon_j]$ is $0$ if $i \neq j$, and $\sigma^2$ otherwise

So here's my derivation. Can someone please point out the error? I believe the answer should be $(n-2)\sigma^2$. If not, please tell me why.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\left(y_i - \hat{y}_i\right)^2}\right] \\
= \mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\left(\beta_0 + x_i\beta_1 + \epsilon_i - \hat{\beta_0} - x_i\hat{\beta_1}\right)^2}\right] \\
= \mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[
\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\left(\beta_0 - \hat{\beta}_0 \right)^2}
+ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{\left(x_i\beta_1 - x_i\hat{\beta}_1 \right)^2}
+ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{\left(\epsilon_i \right)^2}
+ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{2\left(\beta_0 - \hat{\beta}_0 \right)\left(x_i\beta_1 - x_i\hat{\beta}_1 \right)}
+ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{2\epsilon_i\left(\beta_0 - \hat{\beta}_0 \right)}
+ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{2\epsilon_i\left(x_i\beta_1 - x_i\hat{\beta}_1\right)}
\right] \\
= \mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[
n\left(\beta_0 - \hat{\beta}_0 \right)^2
+ \left(\beta_1 - \hat{\beta}_1 \right)^2\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i^2}
+ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{\left(\epsilon_i \right)^2}
+ 2n\bar{x}\left(\beta_0 - \hat{\beta}_0 \right)\left(\beta_1 - \hat{\beta}_1 \right)
+ 2n\bar{\epsilon}\left(\beta_0 - \hat{\beta}_0 \right)
+ 2\left(\beta_1 - \hat{\beta}_1 \right)\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\epsilon_ix_i}
\right] \\
=
n\ \mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[
\left(\beta_0 - \hat{\beta}_0 \right)^2\right]
+ 
\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[\left(\beta_1 - \hat{\beta}_1 \right)^2\right]\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i^2}
+ 
\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon_i^2 \right]}
+ 
2n\bar{x}\ \mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[\left(\beta_0 - \hat{\beta}_0 \right)\left(\beta_1 - \hat{\beta}_1 \right)\right]
+ 
2n\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[\bar{\epsilon}\left(\beta_0 - \hat{\beta}_0 \right)\right]
+ 
2\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[\left(\beta_1 - \hat{\beta}_1 \right)\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\epsilon_ix_i}\right] \\
= 
n\ \mathbb{V}_{\epsilon}\left[
\hat{\beta}_0
\right]
+ 
\mathbb{V}_{\epsilon}\left[
\hat{\beta}_1
\right]\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i^2}
+ 
n\sigma^2
+ 
2n\bar{x}\ 
\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[
\beta_0\beta_1 - 
\beta_0\hat{\beta}_1 - 
\hat{\beta}_0\beta_1 + 
\hat{\beta}_0\hat{\beta}_1  
\right]
- 
2n\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[
\bar{\epsilon}\hat{\beta}_0
\right]
+ 
\left(
2\beta_1\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[\epsilon_i\right]} - 
2\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[\hat{\beta}_1\epsilon_i\right]} 
\right)
\\
=
n\sigma^2\left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{\bar{x}^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}}\right)
+ 
\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}}\left(
\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i - \bar{x})^2} -
\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\bar{x}^2} + 
\sum_{i=1}^{n}{2\bar{x}x_i}
\right)
+ 
n\sigma^2
+ 
2n\bar{x} 
\left(
\beta_0\beta_1 - 
\beta_0\beta_1 - 
\beta_0\beta_1 + 
\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[
\hat{\beta}_0\hat{\beta}_1  
\right]
\right)
- 
2n\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[
\left(
(\beta_0 + \bar{x}\beta_1 + \bar{\epsilon}) - \hat{\beta}_1\bar{x}
\right)
\bar{\epsilon}
\right]
-
2\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[\hat{\beta}_1\epsilon_i\right]} 
\\
= 
\left(
\sigma^2 + \frac{n\sigma^2\bar{x}^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}}
\right)
+ 
\left(
\sigma^2 - 
\frac{n\sigma^2\bar{x}^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}} +
\frac{2n\sigma^2\bar{x}^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}}
\right)
+ 
n\sigma^2
+ 
2n\bar{x} 
\left(
\beta_0\beta_1 - 
\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[
\left(
(\beta_0 + \bar{x}\beta_1 + \bar{\epsilon}) - \hat{\beta}_1\bar{x}
\right)\hat{\beta}_1  
\right]
\right)
- 
2n\left(
0 +
0 + 
\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[\bar{\epsilon}^2\right] - 
\bar{x}\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[\hat{\beta}_1\bar{\epsilon}\right]
\right)
-
2\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[\hat{\beta}_1\epsilon_i\right]} 
\\
= 
2\sigma^2
+ 
\frac{2n\sigma^2\bar{x}^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}}
+ 
n\sigma^2
+ 
2n\bar{x}\left(
\beta_0\beta_1 - \beta_0\beta_1 - \bar{x}\beta_1^2 - \mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[\bar{\epsilon}\hat{\beta}_1\right] + \bar{x}\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[\hat{\beta}_1\ ^2\right]
\right)
- 
2n\left(
0 +
0 + 
\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[\bar{\epsilon}^2\right] - 
\bar{x}\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[\hat{\beta}_1\bar{\epsilon}\right]
\right)
-
0
\\
= 
2\sigma^2
+ 
\frac{2n\sigma^2\bar{x}^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}}
+ 
n\sigma^2
+ 
2n\bar{x}\left(
- \bar{x}\beta_1^2 - 0 + \bar{x}
\left(
\mathbb{V}_{\epsilon}\left[\hat{\beta}_1\right] + \left(\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\left[\hat{\beta}_1\right]\right)^2
\right)
\right)
- 
2n\left(
\frac{\sigma^2}{n} - 0\right)
\\
= 
2\sigma^2
+ 
\frac{2n\sigma^2\bar{x}^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}}
+ 
n\sigma^2
+ 
2n\bar{x}\left(
- \bar{x}\beta_1^2 + 
\frac{\bar{x}\sigma^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}} + \bar{x}\beta_1^2
\right)
- 
2\sigma^2
\\
= n\sigma^2
\end{aligned}
$$

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Hi DevRS. Welcome to MSE! Here is a brief tutorial on how to properly format mathematical expressions https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Hi! IMO your ansatz smells funny. An induvidual residual is $\epsilon_i$, and -- in contrast to your header -- you like to sum the squares of the residuals, that would be $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i^2$. If your simple linear regression model is $y=mx+b$ (I know, that's old school, $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ look so much better), then $\epsilon_i=y_i-(mx_i+b)$. Now explain in your ansatz what is $\hat\beta_0$ and $\hat\beta_1$ and why there is still an $\epsilon_i$.

Hi @AnotherUser! I've replaced the picture with the equation!

Hi @framago! Thanks! Apologies if it looks messy.

@m-stgt I've added some context. Please let me know if this answers your question.

@DevRS -- TY for clarification. Alas I still have some qualms. In first line you express $\epsilon_i$ nicely as $y_i-\hat y_i$ while in line two it shows up in the middle even so you like to express it by other means. Root cause is IMO your model $y=\beta_0+x\beta_1+\epsilon$ -- how do you determine $\epsilon$? Isn't that "silently" included in $\beta_0$? No it is not -- $\epsilon_i$ is part of your sampled $y_i$, all errors are within measured $y_i$. That is why $\epsilon_i=y_i-\hat y_i$ and your model is $y=\beta_0+x\beta_1$ -- nothing more.

@m-stgt $\epsilon_i \neq (y_i - \hat{y}_i)$. I haven't used any symbol to denote the residue for the ith term.

@m-stgt Some additional info: we generally assume that $y = f(x) + e$, where $e$ represents the aleatoric uncertainty. In the case of simple linear regression, we simplify things even further and say that $y = \beta_0 + x\beta_1 + \epsilon$ where \epsilon accounts for both the systematic error (if $f(x)$ isn't of the form $mx + b$) and aleatoric uncertainty. $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are unknowns and we try to approximate them using $\hat{\beta}_0$ and $\hat{\beta}_1$, respectively.
Please let me know if this addresses your qualms?

@DevRS -- Final question: if you go for the model $y=\beta_0+x\beta_1+\epsilon$, after successful approximation you calculate $\hat y=\hat\beta_0+x\hat\beta_1+\hat\epsilon$?

@m-stgt oh no no. Given a true model $y = f(x) + e$, $y = \beta_0 + x\beta_1 + \epsilon$ is the best linear approximation of the true model. If we had infinite samples, we could directly compute $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ without any issues. But since that's not the case, we approximate them. $\hat{\beta}_0$ and $\hat{\beta}_1$ are our approximations of the best possible parameters for linear approximation ie $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$, respectively.
Hope this makes sense.

You have not said what you think the answer should be instead of $n \sigma^2_\epsilon$.  Perhaps $(n-2)\sigma^2_\epsilon$?

Your $2\sigma^2
+
\frac{2n\sigma^2\bar{x}^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}}
+
n\sigma^2
+
2n\bar{x}\left(

\bar{x}\beta_1^2 +
\frac{\bar{x}\sigma^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}} + \bar{x}\beta_1^2
\right)


2\sigma^2$ may have a sign error if you want the $2n\ldots$ terms to cancel.  Knowing the answer, it would also be convenient if the initial $2\sigma^2$ term was not there.

@Henry apologies. I've updated the question with the answer I was expecting. As you've rightly pointed out, it's $(n-2)\sigma^2$. I was hoping to somehow get rid of that $2\sigma^2$ term but couldn't find a way to do so.
